# Normalizar base de datos Producto

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

[image: Modelo relacional mysqlworkbench]

Tengo dudas en la parte de stock.
Quiero tener un historial de los productos que se agregan. y el stock debería tener su propia tabla o estar dentro de producto.
En esa parte estoy super confundido.

Comment: En la tabla almacen.

Comment: Respuesta: Depende! Si tienes un kárdex, entonces cada ingreso debe mantener su cantidad por separado en un mismo producto, porque ingresa con un costo diferente. Si sólo tienes una cantidad de sillas azules y no importa lo que comenté, pues puedes mantenerlo en el producto y actualizarlo con cada ingreso o venta (con un trigger, etc). Tu pregunta, como está, es muy amplia porque no tenemos idea de cuáles son los requerimientos de tu modelo

Comment: Yo tendría una tabla de productos. Esa tabla indica los productos actuales, activos o en servicio. Luego otra tabla stock que contiene el stock actual en la empresa de esos productos y una tercera con el histórico de movimientos de entrada o salida al stock de los productos. Con eso te aseguras tener actualizado el stock, un histórico de entradas/salidas y además puedes calcular el stock que había un día determinado.

Comment: En los requerimientos no piden mas detalles, pero trato de preparar el sistema para un futuro que se pueda necesitar otros requerimientos con productos diferentes y sus costos.. Pero la sugerencia de Juan Enrique me sirve por ahora. Gracias.